# Memory Game Reset button, glitching out

Tags: javascript

My problem here, is i have a memory game... this function i put below is a reset button, so it clears the boards, initiates a new board (that assigns something to random cards each time)  and resets the timer.   The timer only runs when a card is clicked, that is why i remove the display at the bottom.  I had an issue that whenever i clicked multiple times on the reset button, (reset a game 2 times throughout, or just clicked the reset button a few times) the game glitched, lagged and ultimately it doesnt create a great game...

i added the line wait(); because i didnt know what i was doing... lol   it created an error in the console... saying wait(); was not a defined function... but my game started working correctly!   ultimately i need to find a way to get the performance that is happening with this error, to happen without the error.  any help would be appreciated... i linked my CodePen below with the wait(); removed.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nique0401/pen/GdKmaq)

```
let wait = 500;
let opened = [];

function resetTimer(timer) {
  $(".restart").on("click", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < sCards.length; i++) {
      $(".card").remove();
    }
    opened = [];
    init(); //recreates the cards
    wait(); //shows an error in console, but makes game work correctly?
    $(".timer").css("display", "none");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue I found out after playing around with your Codepen,

`resetTimer()` function is unnecessary here keep it as `$(".restart").on("click", function() { ... })` will do.

Remove `resetTimer(nowTime);` from `init()`

Reason of your game glitches out was because of the function `resetTimer()`

In `init()`, you have execute `resetTimer(nowTime)` in the for loop and make the function executed for 16 times due to have 16 shuffled card

Edited codepen example provided. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxErYY)

Comment: So i was just overcomplicating things by adding the function resetTimer.   Thank you for your help! i tested it out on the master, and it works just as i wished!

Comment: No problem, it wasn't bad by adding the function resetTimer, but make sure you execute the function `resetTimer(nowTimer)` outside of `init()` to prevent it for keep on executing